# Product image is not displaying on the list of products ratherdisplaying inside the custom block

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, product-links

kindly have a look on our **site**, first **two new products** are added with image but magento default logo was displaying. Where others are comes up with the theme demo database.

http://52.187.32.74/rahhams

if you open that product in the below link, it will show the actual image that we uploaded, i have tried with your sample image.

http://52.187.32.74/rahhams/chicken-biriyani.html

Let me know anything i have missed while adding the product.

Comment: Select Both **Base** and **Small** role for image in product from admin.

Comment: I can able to see "Hover Image" role on my uploaded image in a particular product. Under Products-> catalog->particular product -> Image And Videos -> i can find my uploaded image but cant able to find Base and Small role over that.

Comment: Click on the image, it will open a siderbar where you can assign different role.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh , In that only am checking i can't assign any other roles than, Finally i fount the solution. In theme they have some attribute set mentioned as default i had a drop down default old, after selecting that one i can able to add base and small role for my product.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fount the solution. In theme they have some attribute set mentioned as default i had a drop down default old, after selecting that one i can able to add base and small role for my product